# SQL query in SQL Server 2017 not working well

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

```
SELECT
    PriceCatalogueID,Replace(Replace(ItemTitle,'%27',''''),'%22','"') as ItemTitle,
    Replace(Replace(CategoryName,'%27',''''),'%22','"') as CategoryName,
    Replace(Replace(Description,'%27',''''),'%22','"') as Description,
    CustomerCode, AllocatedCustomer, ItemCode, Action 
FROM 
    VW_productcatalogue_View  L 
WHERE
    L.CompanyID = 2144   
    AND CategoryName LIKE '%plan%' 
    AND PriceCatalogueID IN (SELECT PriceCatalogueID 
                             FROM tb_Pricecataloguecustomer 
                             WHERE customerid IN (SELECT clientid 
                                                  FROM tb_client 
                                                  WHERE clientName LIKE '%nsw%' 
                                                    AND companyID = 2144 
                                                    AND isDelete = 0))   
 --order by L.PriceCatalogueID asc 
 ORDER BY 
     L.CategoryName ASC
     OFFSET 0 ROWS 
     FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

This is the query dynamically generated by my code.

In the above query, if order by L.CategoryName is done then FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY does not work well.

If order by L.PriceCatalogueID is used, the query works fine.

Can some one guide why this is not working if order by L.CategoryName is used ?

Comment: I suspet `not working well` means `the same rows appear again`. That's because the order inside the category is left to chance. Any paralllel processing step could change the order for any columns that aren't explicitly specified in an `ORDER BY` statement. Subsequent steps *don't* remember what previous queries look like.

Comment: The solution is to explicitly specify the order eg by always adding the ID as the last column in the ORDER BY clause

Comment: Thank you so much.